Is there a way to get the average from the standard deviation in Numpy? (Or a way to feed np.std the average)
I've got an application where I need both the average and the standard deviation of a list of data.
Numpy can calculate both with np.avg and np.std. However, np.std does not give the average, even though you need the average to calculate the standard deviation from first principles. This means I need to use both commands, which is inefficient.
Is there a way to 1) extract the average from np.std (thereby making it unnecessary to run np.avg ), or 2) to give the output from np.avg to np.std (thereby making np.std evaluate faster)?
The documentation suggests there's no way, which is unfortunate =/

Is calling both tbat expensive?  Yes, before computers it was convenient use one to get the othrr.

No, but when you need to do the calculation several hundred thousand times, it does get expensive.

Looks like a future numpy version (2.0+) will allow you to supply the mean to the std https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.std.html#numpy.std

There are 2 basic variance calculations: x@x/N-np.mean(x)**2 and np.mean((x-np.mean(x))**2).  The first is quite a bit faster, even without a precomputed mean.  But according to your link it has some precision issues.  np.var times a bit slower than either, possibly because it is taking more care with some sums.
